# Is there a shortcut in Overleaf for indexing selected words?

Tags: indexing, imakeidx, shortcut

I am writing a text in Overleaf and want to include an index that contains (many) selected words. To do so, I use the `imakeidx` package. Is there a possibility to define a shortcut or a keyboard hotkey such that I mark the word and press the shortkey instead of writing `\index{selected word}` several times?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
In this example several keywords\index{keywords} will be used 
which are important and deserve to appear in the Index\index{Index}.

Terms like generate\index{generate} and some\index{others} will 
also show up. 

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: `\def\z#1{#1\index{#1}` ? then you just need `\z{keywords}`

Comment: Thank you for this answer - this is a great approach!

Since the text has already been written with some abbreviations for my keywords, is there a way to mark the words in the text and then press a keyboard hotkey (e.g., Ctrl + x) to index the words (e.g., like it is working for italics with Ctrl + i)?

Comment: no idea sorry that's an overleaf editor question and I don't use it really other than a few test projects. someone will answer though